# How to make Emacs start in `text-mode` and get rid of LISP message?

Tags: emacs

How can I make Emacs start in `text-mode` and get rid of the following message?

```
;; This buffer is for notes you don't want to save, and for Lisp evaluation.
;; If you want to create a file, visit that file with C-x C-f,
;; then enter the text in that file's own buffer.
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

To get rid of the start message just set the `initial-scratch-message` variable to `""`

```lisp
(setq initial-scratch-message "")
```

To start the scratch buffer in text mode you will want to `initial-major-mode` variable

```lisp
(setq initial-major-mode 'text-mode)
```

For setting of auto-mode when you start a specific major-mode you'll want to add an event to the mode hook

```lisp
(add-hook 'text-mode-hook 'turn-on-auto-fill)
```

Comment: Thanks! One related question: I also want `auto-fill-mode` enabled on startup. I have this in my `.emacs`: `(setq auto-fill-mode t)` but the `*scratch*` buffer still doesn't have `auto-fill-mode`. How can I enable that automatically on startup?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than fiddle with the way the *scratch* buffer works, I'd recommend you open Emacs with a file argument.  E.g. if you do "emacs foo.txt" chances are it will already start up in text-mode without you having to do anything special for it.

Comment: That is not an option for me. I always open emacs using `emacs` and then start working there with multiple files. Picking one of these files as cmd line arg is just a hack. Also, then people who work on the same machine will see the name of that file when they use `ps` or similar commands. What if my file is called `build-bomb.txt`?

Comment: @Frank: That's fine as well: as soon as you do `C-x C-f` to find a file, again the settings in \*scratch\* won't matter any more.  So my question boils down to: why do you want to use text-mode in the \*scratch\* buffer?

Comment: Because I want to use the scratch space as a text scratch space, to make text notes, not a Lisp scratch space. I'll never write Lisp code, so why should my Emacs start up with a buffer in Lisp-mode?

Answer (score -1):

You only do M-x text-mode in the *scratch* buffer.
That's all.